# $\mid f^{(n)} (t) \mid \leq \frac{M(n!)^s}{R^n}$ then $1/f$ has the same property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, functions

A friend of mine asked me the following problem :

> Let $s \in [1,\infty)$ and $T > 0$.
>
> We say that a function $f \in C^{\infty}([0,T], \mathbb{R})$ is in $\mathcal{K}^s(0,T)$ iff there is $M, R > 0$ such that :
>
> $$\mid f^{(n)}(t) \mid \leq \frac{M(n!)^s}{R^n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, t \in [0,T]$$
>
> Consider a function $g$ such that $g \in \mathcal{K}^s(0,T)$  and such that there is $\delta > 0$ such that $g(t) \geq \delta, \forall t \in [0,T]$then prove that $\frac{1}{g} \in \mathcal{K}^s(0,T)$

I don’t know how to approach this problem. The assumption made on $g$ are difficult to understand intuitively. We understand that it means that $g$ is extremely regular but then how can I conclude that $1/g$ has the same property.

An idea is to use binomial theorem to expand the derivative but it doesn’t really work since the expression of $(1/g)^{(n)}$ depend on some of the derivative of $1/g$.

Comment: $1/g$ could be unbounded if $g=0$ at some point?

Comment: @MisterRiemann Yes thank you for noticing, I forgot an assumption. Now it’s ok.

Comment: For a slightly more general version of this assertion, check out Theorem 2.9 (p.14) of [this thesis](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:952969/FULLTEXT01.pdf).